# How do I change font-family and font-size for a CCK form

Tags: embedded-fonts

I am using a Drupal 6.19 Corrolla theme and I have tried several times to change the font-family and font-size of a CCK form but in vain. I could add these CSS statements through Firebug, but could not change them in the style.css. I incorporated several classes in the style sheet, but it has not worked.

I would very much appreciate any help regarding this.

You may find my style sheet at http://zuqaq.com/sites/all/images/style.css.  The website I am working on is http://zuqaq.com.

Answer (score 0):

What is the element that the style should be applied to?
Probably it's just being overriden somewhere.